# How can we count items greater than a value and less than a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this DF.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as sco 

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

data = [['ATTICA',1,2,590,680],['ATTICA',1,2,800,1080],['AVON',14,2,950,1250],['AVON',15,3,500,870],['AVON',20,4,1350,1700]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cities','min_workers','max_workers','min_minutes','max_minutes'])
df

df['Non_HT_Outages'] = (df['min_workers'] < 15).groupby(df['cities']).transform('count')
df['HT_Outages'] = (df['min_workers'] >= 15).groupby(df['cities']).transform('count')
df
```

[image]

I am trying to count items in a column named 'min_workers' and if <15, put into column 'Non-HT' but if >=15, put into column 'HT'. My counts seem to be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `count` to `sum` in the transforms it will work.

This is because `(df['min_workers'] < 15).groupby(df['cities'])` creates a boolean list for each city, with `True` entries when the condition is met and `False` entries when it is not.

`count` gives the count of all the entries, both true and false. `sum` just counts the true ones (treating the trues and falses as 1s and 0s, and summing them).

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right! Thanks! Working too hard today!! Time to logoff now!!!!